# Understanding `None` scheduling preset in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am getting started with Apache Airflow and trying to setup a event driven DAG in Airflow. My event is a file being landed in Linux directory. This file can be landed multiple number of time throughout the day. I am using [File Sensor](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor.html) operator for file monitoring.

My requirement is every time the file lands(with same name) in directory the Dag should kick off.

I was reading the official scheduling documentation and based on my understanding I see with option [None](https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html) I can make my Dag to be triggered externally based on event and it can be triggered multiple times throughout the day based on that external event.

Is my understanding correct? The official documentation doesn't have detailed information on it.

https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html?highlight=scheduling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is correct. Having the schedule_interval as `None` means Airflow will never automatically schedule a run of the Dag.

You can schedule dag_runs externally a few different ways:

- through the [Airflow CLI](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#trigger_dag)
- using a [Local client](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/api/client/local_client.py) from within a python script
- through the [Airflow REST API](https://airflow.apache.org/api.html)
- manually via the trigger button in the Web UI